# Want to make sub domain, but it doesnot work

Tags: nginx, server, dns, subdomain

I want to create a subdomain. But I get an error with the following:

- Original domain root folder linked to `/var/www/html`
- I then configure my subdomain root folder to `/var/www/html/sub.example.com/html`

This is the error as seen in `error.log.1` :

`conflicting server name "sub.example.com" on [::]:80, ignored`

I found this by using `grep sub_domain` but I can't find any error. I got a message using `nginx` syntax that is successful.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the configuration across all included files and identify the `server` blocks with the duplicate `server_name` statements.

Comment: I check server_name statesments by using nginx -t. But there is no symtax error..